# increment interval in a recursive function

Tags: javascript

I have a function which is recursive and on each call it de-increments a max value. I'm trying to increment up the interval vale exponentially.

Each time around I want to increase the interval value.
Right now I only have a n value thats going down in value so I thought if I could reverse that number and use it to increment the interval up in value ? Anyone know a simpler approach to get the interval value to increase each time ?

```
const myFunc = async(fn, n = 3) => {
    const interval = 3000;
    if (n === 1) {
      return 'bailed';
    }
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, interval));
    return myFunc(fn, n - 1);
}
```

Comment: Where does max variable defined?

Comment: re "I'm trying to increment up the interval vale exponentially" - 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000 is not exponential it's very linear.

Comment: @jamiec you are right I should not have given the linear example. Just removed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you already have `n` defined in your recursive function, you can utilize that to generate what the interval should be. I will redefined your code with a few constants to help out.

```js
const MAX_RECURSION = 3;
const INITIAL_INTERVAL = 3000;
const BACKOFF_INTERVAL = 1000;

const myFunc = async (fn, n = MAX_RECURSION) => {
    const interval = INITIAL_INTERVAL + (MAX_RECUSION - n) * BACKOFF_INTERVAL;
    if (n === 1) return 'bailed';
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, interval));
    return myFunc(fn, n - 1);
}
```

This means that for every iteration, the timeout increases by the `BACKOFF_INTERVAL`.

And for the exponential implementation, compared to the first example, you would just need to change the function it uses.

```js
const MAX_RECURSION = 3;
const INITIAL_INTERVAL = 3000;
const BACKOFF_MULTIPLIER = 2;

const myFunc = async (fn, n = MAX_RECURSION) => {
    const interval = INITIAL_INTERVAL * Math.pow(BACKOFF_MULTIPLIER, (MAX_RECUSION - n));
    if (n === 1) return 'bailed';
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, interval));
    return myFunc(fn, n - 1);
}
```

This would lead to the following backoff times given the constants: `3000, 6000, 12000, etc.` You can modify the constants to product different results.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I put in my comment exponentially but then also added a linear example which is what you so kindly did and works great. How would I make this increase exponentially ?

Comment: I added an exponential example. If it answers your question, please don't forget to mark the answer as correct.